# Stylistic error on the JavaScript SDK documentation page

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

There is a small stylistic error on the [JavaScript SDK](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/js-lib) documentation page.

> Your application must have the client side OAuth flow enabled, and must not have **disabled** the desktop application redirect uri **disabled**.

Note the redundant *disabled*. That paragraph should be more like this.

> Your application must have the client side OAuth flow enabled, and must not have the desktop application redirect uri disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.